# Java 8: Merge 2 String Lists into Map

Tags: java, list, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I have the following:

```
List<String> keys
List<String> values
```

I would like map these two lists to a `Map<String, String>` using Java 8 Streams. The lists have both the same size and are sorted the same way.

I tried to map these two with the following

```
Map<String, String> result= keys.stream().
        collect(Collectors.toMap(keys::get, values::get));
```

But this doesnt work at all - how can I do this correclty? 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If your lists are not random access (i.e. if they are linkedlists, for example), you'd better not using a stream to do that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can iterate over the indices of the `List`s with an `IntStream`:

```
Map<String, String> result =
    IntStream.range(0,keys.size())
             .boxed()
             .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> keys.get(i), i -> values.get(i)));
```

Comment: Or `toMap(keys::get, values::get)`